# Metaclass - cannot replace class dict

Tags: python, python-3.x, metaclass

Running this (Python 3.3.1):

```
from collections import OrderedDict


class MyType(type):
    @classmethod
    def __prepare__(*args):
        return OrderedDict()


class MyClass2(metaclass=MyType):

    attr1 = 1
    attr2 = 2
    attr3 = 3
    attr4 = 4
    attr5 = 5

    def __init__(self):
        self.attr6 = 6

    def func(self):
        pass



print(MyClass2.__dict__.items())
```

i am getting:

```
dict_items([('__weakref__', <attribute '__weakref__' of 'MyClass2' objects>), ('__dict__', <attribute '__dict__' of 'MyClass2' objects>), ('__init__', <function MyClass2.__init__ at 0x7f08a106dc20>), ('__doc__', None), ('attr4', 4), ('attr5', 5), ('attr2', 2), ('attr3', 3), ('attr1', 1), ('func', <function MyClass2.func at 0x7f089f995c20>), ('__module__', '__main__')])
```

The class attributes are not sorted by their definition order.

What am i doing wrong to use `OrderedDict` as class `__dict__`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `__prepare__` method in a mataclass allows you to provide your own custom object in place of the `dict` used for class initialisation. However you cannot change the type of object actually used by the class, that will be an instance of an internal type known as `mappingproxy` and is unordered. If you want to preserve the order in which the attributes where defined you must store that separately:

```
class OrderedClass(type):
         @classmethod
         def __prepare__(metacls, name, bases):
            return OrderedDict()

         def __new__(cls, name, bases, classdict):
            result = type.__new__(cls, name, bases, classdict)
            result.member_names = list(classdict.keys())
            return result


class MyClass2(metaclass=OrderedClass):

    attr1 = 1
    attr2 = 2
    attr3 = 3
    attr4 = 4
    attr5 = 5

    def __init__(self):
        self.attr6 = 6

    def func(self):
        pass

>>> MyClass2.member_names
['__module__', '__qualname__', 'attr1', 'attr2', 'attr3', 'attr4', 'attr5', '__init__', 'func']
```